# Обоснование необходимости повторного вызова функции jQuery, когда объект уже создан

Tags: javascript, jquery

Допустим, мы хотим повесить обработчик события на кнопку

```
var messagesBtn = $("#menu_btn-messages");
```

В переменную `messagesBtn` у нас уже записан объект `jQuery`, и по идее теперь мы можем вызывать методы этого обекта:

```
messagesBtn.on('click', function(){
      ...
    });
```

Тем не менее, насколько я видел в примерах, пишут:

```
$(messagesBtn).on('click', function(){
  ...
});
```

Получается, мы рекурсивно вызываем `$($("#menu_btn-messages"))`. Прокомментируйте, пожалуйста, это явление.

Comment: А вы уверены, что в примерах `messagesBtn` это объект `jq`? (На вопрос: это избыточно и вернется тот же самый объект )

Comment: Насколько я знаю, функция jQuery (сокращённо $), возвращает объeкт jQuery. Я присвоил переменной `messagesBtn` объект jQuery. Что не так?

Comment: Первая часть кода ваша, вторая из каких-то примеров, где связь то между этими кусками кода?

Comment: Я записываю в переменную `messagesBtn ` кнопку с селектором `$("#menu_btn-messages");` и затем переменной `messagesBtn`, значение которой - объект jQuery добавляю обработчик нажания. Вы можете сказать конкретно, что не так?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Когда вы пишете `var messagesBtn = $("#menu_btn-messages")`, вы записываете результат выполнения функции `$()` в переменную `messagesBtn`. В этой переменной хранится состояние элемента на момент присваивания переменной. Зачем так делают? Ну, на то есть как минимум 2 причины.

Первая и главная причина - это оптимизация. Такой процесс, кажется, называется *кэшированием селекторов*, но я могу ошибаться. Короче говоря, при каждом вызове функции `$()` происходят какие-то вычисления, которые тратят ресурсы (поиск элемента, построение jQuery-объекта и т.п.). Чтобы эти ресурсы лишний раз не тратить, объекты jQuery (и не только их - с обычными элементами DOM на ванильном JavaScript делают то же самое) часто помещают в переменные. Вот два теста:

Первый:

```js
var iterations = 1000000;

console.time('Function #1');

for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  $('body').attr('title', 'test');
  $('body').attr('title', 'foo');
  $('body').attr('title', 'baz');
}

console.timeEnd('Function #1');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Второй:

```js
var iterations = 1000000;

console.time('Function #1');

for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
  var $body = $('body');

  $body.attr('title', 'test');
  $body.attr('title', 'foo');
  $body.attr('title', 'baz');
}

console.timeEnd('Function #1');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Лично у меня первый тест выполнялся медленнее второго в 2 раза на Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit) для Windows 10.

На самом деле, подобное кэширование не очень-то и сильно влияет на производительность в реальных условиях. Разница в скорости, конечно, в 2 раза, но обычный вызов функции `$()` выполняется слишком быстро, и если во всем сценарии у вас парочка вызовов, то разницу вы не заметите. Но кэширование нужно использовать, если вы работаете с jQuery из событий, которые выполняются невероятно часто. Например, событие скролла или событие ресайза окна браузера. Было бы неплохо приучить себя постоянно писать с использованием переменных.

Вторая причина, почему так делают - это читаемость кода и удобство его поддержки. Для лучшей читаемости рекомендуется переменные, содержащие jQuery-объект, именовать с символом доллара в начале (чтобы обозначить, что в переменной находится jQuery-объект), как во втором тесте, и давать имя, основанное не на имени класса или ID, а на значении (назначении) элемента. Таким образом, вы можете изменить имя селектора лишь в одном месте и не бояться, что вы где-то что-то забыли.

Что происходит, когда вы передаете jQuery-объект в функцию `$()`, например `$($("#menu_btn-messages"))`? Да ничего интересного и необычного. Разработчики jQuery таким образом лишь предотвратили возможные путаницы в коде. Но так делать не рекомендуется - это лишняя трата ресурсов.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за идеальный ответ! Всё понял.

Comment: Очень познавательно, спс за ответ.